# Octokit.net extremely slow

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, octokit.net

I am trying to use Octokit.net to interact with GitHub inside a simple C# console application (Visual Studio 2019, .NETCore 3.1), and I am experiencing an ***extreme* slowness** issue.

Directly calling by Postman the GitHub api with the following GET request:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/OrganizationName/RepoName/commits
```

provides response in at most **1500 milliseconds**, while getting the same info by:

```
var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("my-test"));
client.Credentials = new Credentials(MY_TOKEN); //same token used in Authentication header when calling API by Postman

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Begin to await...");

IReadOnlyList<GitHubCommit> commits = await client.Repository.Commit.GetAll("OrganizationName", "RepoName");

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Await finished...");
```

lets me wait for as long as **3 *minutes***!

Any idea on how to speed up the process to at most a couple of seconds?

--- EDIT

As pointed out by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) in the comments, the request I sent by Postman was faster just because it retrieves just a page of commits, while my Octokit code retrieves *really all* commits.

With the following edit Octokit just retrieves a single page of 100 commits:

```
ApiOptions options = new ApiOptions
            {
                PageSize = 101,
                PageCount = 1
            };
IReadOnlyList<GitHubCommit> commits = await client.Repository.Commit.GetAll("OrganizationName", "RepoName", options);
```

Comment: Does it definitely get the same info? Is it possible that the Postman call is only making a single request, getting a single page of information, whereas your Octokit code is getting *really all* the commits? Check how many commits you're getting in each case.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: you may be quite right! Since the commits retrieved by postman are as old as one year, and I'm not interested in older commits, is there a way to tell Octokit to just get a single page too? I mean last 1000 commits would be more than enough, thank you.

Comment: Yes, specify an `ApiOptions` - you can specify the starting page number, the page count, and the page size.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks! With PageCount=1 and PageSize set from 1 to 100 it retrieves me the corresponding number of items, but if I set PageSize=1000 or even PageSize=101, it still retrieves just 100 elements. Is 100 the upper limit for a page? I need more or less 1000 commits. Is the only way to get 10 pages with 100 commits each? How can i reassemble those 10 pages in a single 1000 element list/array? Thank you very much!

Comment: Octokit assembles the pages for you. It *sounds* like 100 is the maximum page size, but I don't know - consult the GitHub documentation. It sounds like you just want to specify a page count of 10 and a page size of 100.